# How to limit scanf function in C to print error when input is too long?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

I want to limit the scanf function so when I enter for example a `char* array <String...>` that has more then 30 characters, it will not get it and my output will be error.

I got a hint to use [^n] or something like that but I don't understand how to do it?
I know that I can use `scanf("%30s"..)` but I don't want the input to be valid and just the error.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't such a thing. Given 30 characters that match your conversion spec, it'll succeed, regardless of whether there might be more that would as well. It's up to you to read the next character and verify that it's a new-line, or something like that (but that still won't put back the 30 characters you read).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you must use `scanf` then I believe that the best that you can do is use the width specifier with something like: `"%31s"`, as you've already mentioned, then use `strlen` to check the length of the input, and discard the string and report an error if the input is longer than your limit.

Or possibly skip the `strlen` by additionally using an `%n` in your format string, e.g. `"%31s%n"`.

A format string using something like `%[^\n]` in place of `%s` simply instructs the function to continue reading until a newline, consuming other whitespace characters along the way. This is useful if you want to allow the input to include whitespace characters.

Review the docs for scanf ([here's](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) a copy of the man page).

Comment: I think you meant to say `%31[^\n]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `fgets` and `sscanf`. With `fgets` you can read a little bit more than `30` characters and then check that you didn't get more than `30` characters.

Or if you really want to use `scanf` use it with something more than `30` like `%32s`.

Comment: Our proffessor told us to use scanf unfortunately , and gave a hint - scahnf("%[^n\*c) but i don't get it :O

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this page http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf and look for the *%n* format specifier.  I would also recommend looking the sscanf function's return value, which will tell you the number of formatted arguments, as well as the presence of error.

I've used the *%n* format specifier to help in parsing a string of parameters:

```
        ret = sscanf(line, "%d %d %s %d %d %n", &iLoad, &iScreen, &filename, &stage, &bitmapType, &offset);
```

The number of chars formatted by the preceding arguments is stored in the variable *offset*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use getchar in a loop, and count the characters coming in.

```
  int iCharCount = 0;

  ch = getchar();
  while( ch != EOF ) {
      iCharCount++;
      if(30 < iCharCount)
      {
        printf("You have attempted to enter more than 30 characters.\n");
        printf("Aborting.");
        break;
      }
      printf( "%c", ch );
      ch = getchar();
   }
```

This is a crude example. If it were up to me, I'd allocate a maximum-sized character array, read the whole line in, and then use string utilities to count it, edit it, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Well in C you can do:

```
#include <string.h>

...

if(strlen(array_ptr) > 0) error();
```

Obviously you need a bigger buffer to actually first get the input to it, and then check it's length, so the array could be of e.g. 512 bytes. When you copy strings to it, you need to check that you are getting 0 at the end.

Comment: :-) So you've been asked to handle error codes from scanf function - well, the scanf returns number of matches, but if the codes on the match, or how to specify it, it looks a bit tricky question. You should be on the lessons you would know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` ,is very good for this kind of thing, but a careful `scanf` can do the trick here too. You'll want to make sure that you're correctly limiting the number of characters the user can enter, so %31s would mean that 30 chars max + the `\0` null terminator (31).

What you're preventing is buffer overflow attacks, which can be extremely effective ways to break sloppily written c programs. Here's an excellent article by Aleph One on BO:
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html