# Is it possible to allocate the correct amount of space to strings in C during run time?

Tags: c, char, runtime, c-strings, dynamic-allocation

Is there any way to allocate ***exactly*** enough space during runtime WITHOUT asking the length of the string?

```
int main() 
{
    char **tests;
    int counter;
    int i;
    int j;
    int testCases;

    scanf(" %d", &testCases);

    tests = malloc(sizeof(char *) * testCases);

    for(i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    //stuck here, normally I would put tests[i] = malloc(length_of_string)
    //but I don't know the length of string until runtime
}
```

Comment: Unless file input is an option, not that I know of

Comment: @juice What is the problem? If you don't know length, find it out using strlen function, this seems very easy to me, so I doubt that have interpreted your question correctly. Can you add information how you get strings?

Comment: @juice strings are not null terminated or what?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886594/how-to-limit-scanf-function-in-c-to-print-error-when-input-is-too-long and/or http://www.mkyong.com/c/how-to-handle-unknow-size-user-input-in-c/

Comment: use `int main (int arc, char **argv )` Give the #testcases as input parameter and use `strnlen()` to get the length of the input.

Comment: Show the source of the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `scanf` to read the count, I suppose that you will be using it to read the strings as well. If your C library is Posix 2008  compatible [Note 1], then you can use the `m` length modifier to a scanf `%s` `%c` or `%[` format, which will cause `scanf` to automatically allocate the string for you. (You need to supply the address of a string pointer -- i.e. `char**` -- instead of just a string pointer.)

Note that in the scanf format `" %d"`, the space character is redundant. The `%d` format specifier, like `%s`, automatically skips leading whitespace.

Here's an example if you are reading white-space separated words:

```
int n_strings;
if (scanf("%d", &n_strings) != 1) {
  /* Handle input error; do not continue */
}
/* Should check to make sure n_strings is > 0 */
char** strings = malloc(n_strings * sizeof *strings);
if (!strings) {
  /* Handle alloc error; do not continue */
}
for (int i = 0; i < n_strings; ++i) {
  if (scanf("%ms", &strings[i]) != 1) {
    /* Handle input error, do not continue */
  }
}
```

It's more likely that you will be wanting to read in complete lines. In that case, again using a Posix 2008 compatible library, you can use the `getline` function, which reads an entire line -- including the newline character -- and stores it into malloc'd storage. Unlike the `scanf` `m` modifier, `getline` requires that the buffer pointer whose address you give it is either NULL or the result of a previous call to `malloc`. Also, a successful call will return the number of characters actually stored, which can be handy.

Here's the above example using `getline`:

```
int n_strings;
if (scanf("%d", &n_strings) != 1) {
  /* Handle input error; do not continue */
}
/* Skip the rest of the first line */
while (getchar() != '\n') {}
char** strings = malloc(n_strings * sizeof *strings);
if (!strings) {
  /* Handle alloc error; do not continue */
}

for (char **strp = strings, **limit = strings + n_strings;
     strp < limit;
     ++strp) {
  size_t n = 0;
  *strp = NULL;
  ssize_t len = getline(strp, &n, stdin);
  if (len <= 0) {
    /* Handle input error, do not continue */
  }
  /* You probably don't want the trailing newline. But remember
   * that is is possible that it doesn't exist if the last character
   * in the file is not a newline.
   */
  if (len && (*strp)[len - 1] == '\n')
    (*strp)[len - 1] = 0;
}
```

---

1. As far as I know, the standard C library will conform to Posix 2008 if you are using reasonably modern Linux or Mac OS X. Both the features recommended here were implemented in the Gnu standard C library before being incorporated into the standard.

   To enable Posix 2008 features, you will need to put one (or both) of these lines in your source code *before* any system include:

   ```
   #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
   ```

   If you are using an older `glibc`, in which `getline` and the `m` flag were still considered Gnu extensions, use this definition:

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Read a little bit at a time using a fixed buffer and as you go realloc the memory.  You can't use scanf.  It will ignore all white spaces.

```
#define BUFSIZE 100
#define INITIALSIZE 20

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    char **tests;
    int counter;
    int i;
    int j;
    int testCases;

    scanf(" %d", &testCases);
    // get rid of the CR/LF
    fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stdin );

    tests = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * testCases);

    for(i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
        int availableSpace, newSize;
        availableSpace = newSize = INITIALSIZE;
        tests[i] = (char *)malloc(availableSpace * sizeof(char));   
        tests[i][0] = '\0';
        while ( fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stdin ) != NULL )
        {

            if ( availableSpace <= (int) strlen(buf) ) {
                newSize += (int) strlen(buf) - availableSpace + 1;
                tests[i] =  (char *)realloc(tests[i], newSize * sizeof(char));
                availableSpace = 0;
            }
            else {
                availableSpace -= strlen(buf);
            }
            strcat(tests[i], buf);
            if (strlen(buf) < BUFSIZE-1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that both `strlen(s)` takes `O(length of s)` and `strcat(s, t)` takes `O(length of s + length of t)`, no? But the more serious issue is your test for completion; it cannot distinguish between a continuation segment and a final newline-terminated line which has exactly BUFSIZ-2 characters before the newline; in the latter case, it will incorrectly append the next line, leading to a really annoying bug. (Annoying because it will happen very rarely, making diagnosis difficult.)