# Best way of input in C console application: Differences between different types of inputting string in a console application C

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, gets

Hi have been doing research and I have found three most common different types of input inside a C console application:

- **scanf("%[^\n]s", *char):** Pick up a string until it finds a break line. It is advised not to use it due to overflow buffer problems.
- **gets(*char):** Pick up a string until it finds a break line. It is equivalent to the first. It is advised not to use it due to overflow buffer problems too.
- **fgets(*char, LENGTH, *FILE):** Pick up a string of LENGTH characters, from the file FILE. It is the safest of the three and the most recommended.

Having said this, I will show an example (MCVE) of the use of the three functions and what is picking up them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char hello[7]; //Will store word 'hello'; Length is 6 = 5+(1)+1 = strlen("hello")+(BreakLineChar)+NullTermination - BreakLineChar will appear (or not) depending input type
    int i;

    // SCANF()
    printf("Input HELLO: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",hello);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(hello));
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(hello); i++)
    {
        printf("%i: %c\n", i, hello[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    // GETS()
    printf("Input HELLO: ");
    gets(hello);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(hello));
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(hello); i++)
    {
        printf("%i: %c\n", i, hello[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    // FGETS()
    printf("Input HELLO: ");
    fgets(hello,sizeof(hello),stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Length: %d\n", strlen(hello));
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(hello); i++)
    {
        printf("%i: %c\n", i, hello[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This code, have next output:

```
Input HELLO: hello
Length: 5
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o


Input HELLO: hello
Length: 5
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o


Input HELLO: hello
Length: 6
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o
5:




Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.757 s
Press any key to continue.
```

So, as we can see, three conclusions can be drawn from this:

- **scanf:** Pick up user's input until '\n' char (does not pick up the character '\n'). So string `hello` would be:

`hello[0] = 'h'`

`hello[1] = 'e'`

`hello[2] = 'l'`

`hello[3] = 'l'`

`hello[4] = 'o'`

`hello[5] = '\0'`

- **gets:** Equivalent to the point above. So string `hello` would be:

`hello[0] = 'h'`

`hello[1] = 'e'`

`hello[2] = 'l'`

`hello[3] = 'l'`

`hello[4] = 'o'`

`hello[5] = '\0'`

- **fgets:** Pick up user's input until '\n' char (pick up the character '\ n' too). So string `hello` would be:

`hello[0] = 'h'`

`hello[1] = 'e'`

`hello[2] = 'l'`

`hello[3] = 'l'`

`hello[4] = 'o'`

`hello[5] = '\n'`

`hello[6] = '\0'`

Are my conclusions correct? Any information to add?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be more interesting, I think, if you typed a longer string as input, like "supercalafragalisticexpialidocious" or something.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s",hello);`  This is wrong for two reasons. 1) to avoid a buffer overflow, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because this input format specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input. and 2) since the statement read all way to (But not including) the newline, the next character will NEVER be a 's'.  Should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%6[^\n]", hello ) != 1 )  // handle error`

Comment: Hi, @user3629249. Regarding first reason, it is avoided, if you see my answer to this question, you will see how I avoid it using C preprocessor for include a `#define` inside `scanf` clause. Regarding second reason, thank you, I will update my answer including this comprobation. Regards,

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  Per the C standard, this is undefined behavior.  `fflush()` is only for output streams (regardless of what visual studio might allow)

Comment: Oh, ok, Then, for clean `stdin` buffer... which function should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I will make a compilation of all the answers obtained, and of the research work that I continue doing (I will update the answer as I get new information):

- `gets` is insecure, one against it is buffer overflow
- Most safe method for inputting by console is `fgets`, but it have a contra: This command reads '\n' character too. To solve this we can do the following:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #define MAX_SIZE_STRING 5

  int main(void)
  {
      char string[MAX_SIZE_STRING+1]; // MAX_SIZE_STRING + 1 due to a string needs '\0' char at the end
      int i;

      printf("Input a string: ");
      fgets(string, MAX_SIZE_STRING, stdin);

      // Remove '\n' character inside the string:
      string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';
  }
  ```
- `scanf` is a very powerful function, which is necessary to know it thoroughly to use it well. Speaking of `scanf`, I'm going to show an example of how to use `scanf` which controls everything you need (size, when stop reading, avoid bufferOverflow,...):

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #define MAX_SIZE_STRING 5
  #define STR_(X) #X
  #define STR(X) STR_(X)

  int main(void)
  {
      char string[MAX_SIZE_STRING+1]; // MAX_SIZE_STRING + 1 due to a string needs '\0' char at the end
      int i;

      printf("Input a string: ");
      scanf(" %" STR(MAX_SIZE_STRING) "[^\t\n]%*[^\n]", string);
      // EXPLANATION OF THE COMMNAD:
      // First blanck-space: It is used for empty string. If user entries only blank-spaces, it will no stored in the var until user input any char
      // STR(TAM_MAX): Use of preprocessor for adding a max length to the input
      // [^\t\n]: Pick up until find a '\t' or a '\n'
      // So, at the end, this command is equal to: scanf(" %5[^\t\n]s", string);
      // %*[^\n] remove end/break line (\n) so, by this way, buffer overflow is avoied 
  }
  ```

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %" STR(MAX_SIZE_STRING) "[^\t\n]s", string);`  This is not correct,  The next character in the input stream will always be a `\t` or `\n`  So it will never be an `s`

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusions are correct. However, of the three input methods that you reference only `fgets` is safe:

- `scanf` into a string without a limit can overflow an input buffer; see a fix below.
- `gets` is deprecated, because it could not possibly be made safe of buffer overflow ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/335858)).

To fix `scanf` specify the size of your buffer, and leave space for null terminator:

```
scanf("%6[^\n]", hello);
```

Note that `s` at the end is not necessary when you are using `[^\n]` format specifier.

Comment: Oh, Ok! Thank you for your advices. In reference to what you are saying, I have a question: Is there any way of include a define inside `scanf`? (something like: `scanf("%HERE_GOES_MY_INT_DEFINE[^\n]", hello);`)

Comment: @JuMoGar Not really, but [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460098/335858).

Comment: Ok! Thank you again, @dasblinkenlight !

Comment: gets is not deprecated. It is removed from the language. It does not exist.