# using malloc for char variable can not take input data character

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am trying to implement `DMA` for `char` variable. But I am unable to take input. I tried with all the possible cases I know:

```
//gets(ptr_name);
//scanf("%[^\n]", &ptr_name);
//fgets(ptr_name, name, stdin);
```

But I can't even enter input data for the character variable ptr_name. I want to take input as "string with space" as input value. How to solve this problem?
And then how to print the entered name in the screen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
  
int main()
{
    char* ptr_name;
    int name, i;
      
    printf("Enter number of characters for Name: ");
    scanf("%d",&name);
    
    ptr_name = (char*)malloc(name);
    
    printf("Enter name: ");  
    
    //gets(ptr_name);
    //scanf("%[^\n]", &ptr_name);
    //fgets(ptr_name, name, stdin);
                    
    printf("\n Your name is: ");   
         
    puts(ptr_name);  
            
    free(ptr_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DMA tag is for "direct memory access". You probably mean "dynamic memory allocation".

Comment: What happened when you tried to input and output the string? What did you expect and what did you get instead? Please show your input, output and expected output.

Comment: Related: [Do not use gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) and [Input spaces in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d", ...)` does not consume the `enter` so the next `scanf()` gets an empty string.
you can use `getchar()` to consume the `enter`.

Also, you need to allocate additional byte for the zero at the end of the string / string terminator. See the `+ 1` in `malloc()`.

As for your questions, your commented `scanf()` had `&` before argument 2 which isn't expected (`char **` vs. `char *`) but other than that it will allow spaces in strings. `puts()` will print the entered name, alternatively you can modify the above `printf()` to print the name, e.g: `printf("\n Your name is: %s", ptr_name);`

Lastly, please consult [Specifying the maximum string length to scanf dynamically in C (like "%*s" in printf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459980/specifying-the-maximum-string-length-to-scanf-dynamically-in-c-like-s-in-pr) for dynamically limiting the input size, avoiding buffer overflow.

DISCLAIMER: The following is only "make it work" version of the program above and is not intended for real life use without appropriately checking return codes and limiting the input size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* ptr_name;
    int name, i;

    printf("Enter number of characters for Name: ");
    scanf("%d",&name);
    getchar();

    ptr_name = (char*)malloc(name + 1);

    printf("Enter name: ");

    scanf("%[^\n]", ptr_name);

    printf("\n Your name is: ");

    puts(ptr_name);

    free(ptr_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still I can't insert input for name. Screen doesn't wait to enter name, after taking input for name variable, it doesn't allow to take input

Comment: @nischalinn the `conio.h` you included gives me a hint. are you running on microsoft windows or msdos? try to `getchar()` twice.

Comment: I am running on Microsoft Windows 10 and IDE is Dev C++.

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation. It solved my problem as well my concept is also clear. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get input with spaces you need to use getline():

```
getline(&buffer,&size,stdin);
```

here an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main()
{
    char* ptr_name;
    int len;
    printf("Enter number of characters for Name: ");
    scanf("%d",&len);
    ptr_name = (char*)malloc(len);
    printf("Enter name: ");
    getline(&ptr_name, &len, stdin);
    printf("\n Your name is: %s", ptr_name);
    
    free(ptr_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should note that `getline()` is a POSIX function.